# How should I include cdnjs libraries in custom javascript codes in Google tag manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am new to Google analytics and Google Tag Manager and currently I am confused with using external JS libraries. Any help would be appreciated.

I need to use '**https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fingerprintjs2/2.1.0/fingerprint2.min.js**' in my custom javascript code in google tag manager. I have tried to include the script as a **custom html** or even **custom template**. The script is successfully added to the head  and I see it in the inspection. But in my custom JS code , when I try to call and use library functions , it throws exception saying that the lib object is not defined.

I tried **sequencing tags** also , to make sure script loading tags are fired before my custom js code execution. But that did not fix the problem.

Any suggestion on how to include external JS libraries in your GTM custom JS code? I hope I explained the problem properly.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example posted by [jwest75674](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2/issues/371#issuecomment-502362374) should help. As you need to declare **var = fingerprint** in your script to allow Google Tag Manager to capture the data after the script has run

In short, you can copy the script below an add it as Custom HTML Tag in GTM (https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2)

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fingerprintjs2@2.1.0/dist/fingerprint2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var fingerprint; // Variable to allow the Google Tag Manager to capture the data after this script has run.
    if (window.requestIdleCallback) {
      requestIdleCallback(function () {
        Fingerprint2.get(function (components) {
          console.log(components) // an array of components: {key: ..., value: ...}
        })
      })
    } else {
      setTimeout(function () {
        Fingerprint2.get(function (components) {
          console.log(components) // an array of components: {key: ..., value: ...}
        })  
      }, 500)
    }
</script>
```